# Motion sensors to detect the user movent (speed). Is it possible?

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude, sensors, android-sensors

Is it possible to use Motion Sensors to detect the speed at which the user is moving ?? Currently I am planning to use device's GPS but I know it will drain the battery of my device like hell. Is there any way around to detect users speed through my app ??

Any help will be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this can work out:

1. Get speed of the user ONCE using GPS. **(U)**
2. Then keep querying the Accelerometer to get Acceleration along X,Y and Z axis after every T milliseconds. **(T)**
3. Get Resultant acceleration (Remove the acceleration due to gravity component) **(A)**
4. Finally you will have Velocity using this equation : **V = U + A*(T/1000)**
5. Then set U = V;

The accuracy of this approach will depend on :

1. T ==> Lower the value more precise will be the result
2. Accuracy of resultant acceleration calculation
3. Accuracy of Accelerometer
4. Accuracy of initial speed(U)

Comment: I am curious to know if it gives acceptable results.Plz share the accuracy of this approach. Also take units into consideration of all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No!

After about 3 seconds the estimated speed becomes unusable wrong.
The reason is the double integration.

A very detailed video why this cannot work is explained in 
[Google tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) starting at 23:20

However you might use the accelerometer to better detect whether a device is standing still or not (speed = 0), where GPS often fail.